# "foldered" adjective

Tags: adjectives

I'm looking for an adjective that conveys that something is stored *in a folder*. "Foldered". Only no dictionary I browsed treats folder as a verb. And fold, enfold, infold do not seem to carry that specific in-a-folder meaning. Google returns 23800 results for "foldered", though... Should I go with the masses?

Comment: In many cases, but unfortunately not all, the word "filed" will do what you want.

Comment: Stacked in a folder...?

Answer (score 1):

I found a [Wikipedia explanation of *foldering*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foldering) that is more specific than what you have in mind (A communicates with B electronically, without a paper trail, by working in a shared gmail account, writing a draft email, which can be erased after it's been read).

It sounds as though that's not what you're looking for, but rather

**to file**

> to arrange (papers, records, etc.) in convenient order for storage or reference ([dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/file))

The adjective would be *filed*, e.g. *See if the Houseman estate is filed under H, will you?*

Answer (score 1):

*Foldered* appears to be a word that is in use, mostly in a computing context and with an implication of ‘finished’.

“[Folder members (also called foldered objects) -- objects that must be stored in a folder.](http://support.ptc.com/help/windchill/whc/whc_en/index.html#page/Windchill_Help_Center/AccessControlChp_FolderedInfo.html)”

“[All items encapsulated and/or foldered
Located center flat file storage in public area – “Accessions” drawer](https://www.davenportlibrary.com/application/files/5315/4143/4502/2007-25_Griggs-Eldridge-Heden_2007.pdf)”

“[iAssembly Author Include/Exclude Foldered Items](https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/inventor-ideas/iassembly-author-include-exclude-foldered-items/idi-p/5637092?profile.language=tr)”

“[Note if using an SDK to generate the URL, `v1` is automatically added to the URL by default for foldered images](https://support.cloudinary.com/hc/en-us/articles/360001208732-What-URL-conventions-are-invalidated)”

“[Foldered Tasks](https://6wunderkinder.desk.com/customer/portal/questions/17475641-foldered-tasks)”

“[Foldered & Finished: Ora Mae Curry Papers](https://blogs.acu.edu/specialcollections/2019/04/12/foldered-finished-ora-mae-curry-papers/#.XNe20Izmif0)”